# What is the equivalent of a Java HashMap<String,Integer> in Swift

Tags: java, swift, dictionary, swift3

I have an example written in Java that I would like to convert into Swift. Below is a section of the code. I would really appreciate if you can help.

```
Map<String, Integer> someProtocol = new HashMap<>();
someProtocol.put("one", Integer.valueOf(1));
someProtocol.put("two", Integer.valueOf(2));

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : someProtocol.entrySet() {
    int index = e.getValue();
    ...
}
```

NOTE: `entrySet()` is a method of the [`java.util.Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface whereas `getValue()` is a method of the [`java.util.Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) interface.

Comment: I have tried to declare someProtocol as NSMutableDictionary but I had difficulties running it through the for loop.

Comment: Side note: in Java you can do `someProtocol.put("one", 1)`

Comment: You shouldn't convert Java to Swift on a line by line level. That limits your code to only using those features in Swift that have a Java analogue. That's a severe restriction that leads to crappy (Java-level) code. You should instead look at what problem the Java code is solving, and then find the best way of soling that problem in Swift. This technique leads to almost universally better code.

Comment: OP never said he wants to convert it line by line though. For example, I'm looking for the same thing as OP, and I stumbled onto this. The same or similar approach in a different language has being given to me in the answers - so I'd say it's a valid question as well as a valid problem. +1

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I believe you can use a dictionary. Here are two ways to do the dictionary part.

```
var someProtocol = [String : Int]()
someProtocol["one"] = 1
someProtocol["two"] = 2
```

or try this which uses type inference

```
var someProtocol = [
    "one" : 1,
    "two" : 2
]
```

as for the for loop

```
var index: Int
for (e, value) in someProtocol  {
    index = value
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's exactly right. I would omit the first code snippet though, as that's a Swift anti pattern (that's especially common for Java programmers who don't know there are literals). Also, `index` should be a variable in the scope of the `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you for providing this response, it really help me out.

Comment: what about `LinkedHashMap`?

Answer (score 6):

```
let stringIntMapping = [
    "one": 1,
    "two": 2,
]

for (word, integer) in stringIntMapping {
    //...
    print(word, integer)
}
```

Comment: If you are being idiomatic then a `let` might be better than a `var` ;)

Comment: @PauloMattos Good catch

Comment: To reduce confusion between the Java map signature of the OP (`Map<String, Integer>`) and the equivalent in Swift, it should be`String` for the keys (`[String: Int]`) instead of `word`.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it will be something like that:

```
let someProtocol = [
    "one" : 1,
    "two" : 2
]

for (key, value) in someProtocol {
    var index = value
}
```

Comment: You don't need the type annotation on `someProtocol`. You should also rename `someProtocol` and make it a `let` constant

Comment: I left the same name for a dictionary as mentioned in Java code.