# How to create a new data with both string part and a data in bytes, in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am making an app which behaves like cloud storage. I need to upload a file with Alamofire. When I am uploading the related file, I need to append a string which holds path like: "folderName/fileName" (which shows the path on my cloud storage app) to my file data in bytes. I can achieve this by using below code in Java:

```
@Override
protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
   Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();

   params.put("parameterName", new DataPart("folderName/fileName", fileInBytes));
   return params;
}
```

But I don't know how to do this in Swift. I need to create a new Data with a string and a data, before uploading it with Alamofire. How can I achieve that? Any response will be appreciated.

Comment: do you need just a query parameter of the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone who answered me, I've found a solution. I created a structure called DataPart with a string and data, and put that parameter to my Alamofire request with parameter name.
"[What is the equivalent of a Java HashMap<String,Integer> in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44637836/what-is-the-equivalent-of-a-java-hashmapstring-integer-in-swift)" this entry helped me a lot in case you are wondering.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you want to convert your path (of type `String`) to swift's `Data` structure, then upload it to your server alongside a joined file's data.

so here's how you can do it-

```
let path = "folderName/fileName"
let pathEncodedData = path.data(using: .utf8)!

let fileData: Data = #YourFile'sData

let params = ["path": pathEncodedData, "fileData": fileData]
```

Comment: Sorry I guess I couldn't explain myself clearly in the question. I added an answer to my question.